# Basis functions that are one at a point and zero at others

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, exponential-function, finite-element-method

## 1D basis functions

In 1D space, I'm looking for a set of [basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function) like below. They would be equal to one at certain points and zero at others.

[image: Schematic 1D]

### 2D schematics

In 2D space, the basis function could be something below, taken from [this reference](https://mfem.org/tutorial/fem/):

[image: Schematic FEM 2D]

## Sigmoid?

I don't want a conditional function with `if` and `else`. I'm just looking for a straightforward function that is easy to handle. Like what Sigmoid function provides for the *step* behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

### Derivate of sigmoid

I was thinking about using derivative of the sigmoid function:

[image: Derivative of sigmoid function]

## Question

Can anyone shed some light on the subject I'm exploring. Am I on the right path? Can sigmoid derivative be used as my basis functions?

## Update

I realized I may be looking for a bump function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function but without the `if else` condition.

Comment: The derivative of the sigmoid is strictly positive on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oh, right. I want my basis functions to be zero outside a limited range.

Comment: Other than the trick of using extensively $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$ and $\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+\lvert b-a\rvert}2$, I don't really know what to suggest. I doubt this is going to provide anything but functions that are continuous on their domain, and I doubt you can manage to obtain a smooth function that is $0$ outside some region.

Comment: So for instance your $\phi:\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ could be $$\phi(x)=\max\left(0,\min\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta},\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)\right)=\\ =\frac{\frac{\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}+\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}-\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)^2}}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}+\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}-\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)^2}}2\right)^2}}{2}$$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks. I'm going to plot your last suggested basis function and see how it looks like.

Comment: It's easier if you simplify first.

Answer (score 0):

The function $ \phi:\Bbb R\to [0,1] $ suggested by @SassatelliGiulio works:

$$ \phi(x) = \max\left(0,\min\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta},\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)\right) $$

Which leads to:

$$ \phi(x) = \frac{\frac{\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}+\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}-\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)^2}}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}+\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{x-x_0+\delta}{\delta}-\frac{x_0+\delta-x}{\delta}\right)^2}}2\right)^2}}{2} $$

For $x_0 = 0.25$ and $\delta = 0.125$, the plot is:

[image: Plot]

The integral of the above plot from `0` to `1` is `0.125`.